# using push notification using on visual studio on genymotion

Tags: azure, push-notification, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I followed the link given below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-push/#optional-configure-and-run-the-app-on-android

I also built the quick start azure project as said by your tutorial.
Now that I am trying to run the app on genymotion emulator (I have installed google play services in it) the build is giving me many errors

[please click on the link of the image to see the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqQDw.jpg)

PS: The process is giving build errors so using genymotion is actually not a problem
Someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you are missing a dependency from the Android SDK.  Open up the Android SDK Manager and install google play services.  If you installed the Android SDK as part of the Visual Studio install, you may need to run the SDK Manager as Administrator to do the install.

Comment: Can you tell me which all files should I download underneath
 Android X.0 (API X)
In the andorid SDK?

Comment: Android 6.X (N) doesn't have the right packages yet.  Under Android 6.0 (Marshmallow), install "Google APIs * System Image" (at least one) and under SDK Tools, install "Google Play services"